# Output port missing in generated Verilog code from MyHDL

Tags: verilog, myhdl

I am trying to generate a verilog module from the following MyHDL module:

top.py:

```
from myhdl import *
from counter import Counter

def Top(clkIn, leds):
    counter = Counter(clkIn, leds)
    return counter

clkIn = Signal(bool(0))
leds = intbv(0)[8:0]

toVerilog(Top, clkIn, leds)
```

and,

counter.py:

```
from myhdl import *

def Counter(clk, count):
    c = Signal(modbv(0)[8:0])

    @always(clk.posedge)
    def logic():
        c.next = c + 1

    @always_comb
    def outputs():
        count.next = c

    return logic, outputs
```

However, in the generated file's module definition, (lines 1-3)

top.v:

```
module top (
    clkIn
);

input clkIn;
reg [7:0] counter_c;

always @(posedge clkIn) begin: TOP_COUNTER_LOGIC
    counter_c <= (counter_c + 1);
end

assign count = counter_c;

endmodule
```

`leds[7:0]` are missing. Even though these LEDs are unused I need them for my synthesizer to assign them to the proper pins on the development board. Why is MyHDL omitting them? and how can I make it include them?

Comment: I didn't use MyHDL but it seems to me `leds = intbv(0)[8:0]` is assigning 0 to your leds signal.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler: It is indeed assigned 0. As I have understood it, this is only for determining the initial value during simulation. This value is  increased when simulating the circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `leds = intbv(0)[8:0]` into `leds = Signal(intbv(0)[8:0])`. 
Module (output) ports need to be declared as `Signal`.

Answer (score 0):

In your module top design, you didn't declare leds as an output. On clkIn is defined and it is an input.  Most synthesizers will check that logic is driving outputs or some other visible, or kept logic.  If the synthesizer determines that there is no possible way for you tell that leds is present in the design externally, it may just optimize it away as well as any dedicated logic driving it, away.

If this is Altera, there is a qsf assignment called virtual pins which could be assigned to leds, to keep it.   But the easy thing to do is add leds to the module top pin definition and assign it as an out.

Per the comment from Alper, you don't assign Count to anything.  That needs to be fixed.

Also, you don't initialize counter in the Counter definition.  This might work in synthesis because the logic will either init to zeros, or some other definitive value, but in simulation, the value may (probably/will) remain unknown.  Get a reset signal if you can.

Comment: If I am not completely misunderstanding your answer, I think you have misunderstood my question. I am using MyHDL to generate that Verilog file, top.v. This is done from the input files top.py and counter.py. And, yes, it needs to be assigned as an output in the module definition; My question is: How do I get MyHDL to do that from the Python input files? And, yes, I know I need to add a reset signal. I actually already have, but I narrowed the code down to provide a minimum example.